# Can't ssh to my iphone: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, iphone, openssh

I'm trying to establish ssh connection from my laptop(macbookpro) to my iphone.
when trying to copy keys from laptop to iphone getting:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub mobile@iphone.local
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

When trying to ssh just with password authentication getting basically the same:

```
$ ssh -vvv mobile@iphone.local
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to iphone.local [192.168.1.53] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

scanning of port 22 of my iphone gives this:

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -sV -p 22 iphone.local
Password:

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-09 14:43 PDT
Nmap scan report for iphone.local (192.168.1.53)
Host is up (0.096s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE    VERSION
22/tcp open  tcpwrapped
MAC Address: D8:BB:2C:83:F8:84 (Unknown)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.45 seconds
```

"tcpwrapped" state of port instead of OpenSSH version is really strange and confusing... But I believe it shows that something wrong with server config.

Keys are fine, because I can use them to connect to another host successfully. Trying to generate another keys - did not make any changes.

iphone **/etc/ssh/sshd_config:**

```
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

PermitRootLogin yes
#PermitRootLogin without-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange no

UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox      # Default for new installations.

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

What's the problem? Can anybody point me to the right direction?

OpenSSH version on iphone:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH 6.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 11 Jun 2015
```

I believe, i launched the process correctly with

```
# launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist
```

I've already tried to remove **known_hosts** and all **/etc/ssh/ssh_host_** on iphone... Run out of ideas.((

**UPDATE**

Tried this:

```
$ telnet iphone.local 22
Trying 192.168.1.53...
Connected to iphone.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

==> No sshd banner.

**EDIT**

I've checked if the server runs on my iphone:

```
ps aux | grep [s]shd
```

I should have got a line such as:

```
root 749 0.0 0.0 55164 5428 ? Ss Aug09 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

but i didn't. Seems like it was my problem. Now I have to find out how to start the process on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we work our way down:

Your ssh connection attempt output mentions this error:

```
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/Andryuwka/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

1. Does this file exist?
2. Can this identity be used to login to other hosts (= is not corrupted)
3. If you move this identity, and generate a new one with ssh-keygen, do you still get the same error?

Concerning the nmap output:

Do you know about https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_tcpwrapped : "Specifically, it means that a full TCP handshake was completed, but the remote host closed the connection without receiving any data."

==> Do you get an SSH server banner when you:

```
telnet iphone.local 22
```

? Should look something like:

```
# telnet localhost 22
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_<SomeVersionNumer>
```

==> Can you connect with an SSH-Client on the iphone to the SSH-Server on the iphone?

==> If not, can you confirm, the process is running on the iphone? e.g.:

```
ps aux | grep [s]shd
```

You should get a line such as:

```
root 749 0.0 0.0 55164 5428 ? Ss Aug09 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

If not, there is your problem: There is no sshd running

Comment: 1. file exists; 2 . I'm using it successfully to login to other host; 3. I moved these files out and generated new pair of keys and got absolutely the same error when tried `ssh-copy-id` again.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that there is something wrong with my sshd_config... But what? I have to say that I also can successfully connect from iphone to laptop..

Comment: Edited the post... nmap gives strange "tcpwrapped" state of port 22 instead of openssh version...

Comment: I don't have files **/etc/tcp.*** on iphone... Is it strange? lol and regarding the `telnet iphone.local 22` see my post updated

Comment: thanx for explanation regarding nmap... I've updated the post

Comment: as I've said before I don't have files **/etc/tcp.alow** and **/etc/tcp.deny** on iphone... Also I'm not sure how can I check if process is running on iphone (What I've done is this (as root): `# launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist `) - so I believe everything is run. Speaking about connectin from iphone to iphone: `$ ssh mobile@iphone.local` gives the same error

Comment: So `ps aux | grep ssh` gives me `mobile   926    0.0    0.0    535232   388   s000   S+    4:30PM   0:00.01 grep ssh` . What exactly should /etc/tcp.allow contain?

Comment: well how to get the server run on ios? I was thincking reboot should solve a problem, but it's not helping... `launchctl load ... ` did not help too

Comment: @Andrew, add some of the information you posted down here back to your Question. Then mark my answer as accepted (It answers why you cant connect: "It's not running"). Then open a new one with "how to install and verify sshd on IOS"

Comment: done. http://superuser.com/questions/954492/how-to-start-ssh-server-on-ios