# how to start ssh server on iOS?

Tags: networking, ssh, iphone, openssh, ios

I can't connect to my iphone via ssh. device is jailbroken and has openssh installed:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH 6.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 11 Jun 2015
```

I've found out that for some reason it doesn't have the server process started(my other post: [Can't ssh to my iphone: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host](https://superuser.com/questions/954420/cant-ssh-to-my-iphone-ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote))

Although I've run on my iphone(as root):

```
# launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.openssh.sshd.plist
```

But

```
$ ps aux | grep [s]shd
```

returns nothing, instead of something like:

```
root 749 0.0 0.0 55164 5428 ? Ss Aug09 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

So there is the question:

How can I start my ssh server on my iphone?

And/Or

Verify a correct installation?

**EDIT:**

Well I got it!

so `$(which sshd)` returned me something like:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

So I've found this solution online:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165382

On my iphone I run:

```
$ su
# $(which ssh-keygen) -A
# $(which sshd)
```

and after that nmaped iphone from my laptop (to check if it worked):

```
sudo nmap -sS -sV -p 22 iphone.local
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-09 18:00 PDT
Nmap scan report for iphone.local (192.168.1.53)
Host is up (0.058s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.7 (protocol 2.0)
MAC Address: D8:BB:2C:83:F8:84 (Unknown)
```

DONE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running sshd in the foreground to prove correct installation:

1. Find it: `which sshd`
2. Run it: `sshd`
3. Report Output

You could try `sshd | tee ~/ssh.out` (if IOS has 'tee'), else `sshd >> ~/ssh.out`

Comment: how to write the output to the file? something like `/usr/sbin/sshd | cat >> ~/ssh.out` in iOS?